# What is the role of NaCl in the functionalization of gold nanoparticles?

Tags: synthesis, nanotechnology

In the functionalization of gold nanoparticles (GNPs) through the sulfur-metal bond, [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0956566310004094) (among others) states that $\ce{NaCl}$ is slowly added in the GNPs solution after addition of thiol compound.

What is the role of $\ce{NaCl}$ in the functionalization step?

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{NaCl}$ acts as a charge suppressor so that the negatively charged gold nanoparticle and a negatively charged ligand (with thiol) are not longer charge repelled and can experience a chemical bond. $\ce{NaCl}$ is easily broken into $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ so that the $\ce{Na+}$ can pacify the negative charge on the surface of the gold nanoparticle to become less negative and approach zero charge. Other higher charged salts such as $\ce{Mg^2+}$ impart even greater pacification.

Here are some good references:

- J Liu, Y Lu. Preparation of aptamer-linked gold nanoparticle purple aggregates for colorimetric sensing of analytes. Nature protocols, 2006. nature.com
- B Du, Z Li, Y Cheng. Homogeneous immunoassay based on aggregation of antibody-functionalized gold nanoparticles coupled with light scattering detection. Talanta, 2008. Elsevier. From this last ref:

> in $\pu{10 mM}$ phosphate-buffered solution (pH 7.0) containing $\pu{1.0 mmol L−1} ~\ce{NaCl}$ at room …